# LibGDX - How to use a skin after loading it in the assetManager

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm having trouble using the skin once I've loaded it in the assetManager.

```
    assetManager.load(skinPath+".atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
    assetManager.finishLoading();


    assetManager.load(skinPath+".json", Skin.class, new SkinLoader.SkinParameter(skinPath+".atlas"/*,Resources*/));
    assetManager.finishLoading();

    skin = skin.get(skinPath+".json", Skin.class);
```

The last line of code throws `java.lang.NullPointerException`, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

```
skin = skin.get(UIAssetsPath+skinName+".json", Skin.class);
```

skin.get() is your issue here. As skin is null and I am not sure why are you trying to get skin from a skin when you have your asset loader.

You need to call

```
assetManager.get(UIAssetsPath+skinName+".json", Skin.class);
```

Also suggest you reading more about exceptions. This seems a very beginner mistake.

Comment: ahh, didn't notice, sorry.

Comment: What about exceptions I don't understand?

Comment: well NullPointerException is usually self describing. The stacktrace says where its happening at it means one of your variable is null. If you are unable to figure out from it then you need to read more about exceptions.

Comment: oh I know, I was searching over the method 'get' where there could be some uninitialized variable, didn't even notice I was calling it from skin xd